# Existing iOS 7 and iOS 8 Apps with Core Data and iCloud, but not with iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud

I have an existing app in the App Store which uses Core Data and iCloud as a mechanism for storing information locally on users' devices and synchronising across to other devices.

The app works really well on iOS 7 and iOS 8 with the iCloud functionality. I have not done any work to update my app for "iCloud Drive" though because it doesn't seem like what my app requires.

If I enable iCloud Drive on my phone and Macbook Pro, will that have any impact on the iCloud data? What I mean by this is, if iCloud Drive is enabled, what happens to the apps that use iCloud standard? I'm asking because I want to prepare my users before they upgrade to iCloud Drive.

Comment: hi. this is important issues I think. any update so far?